# How to forcefully run batch in the foreground or restrict batch not to run in background

Tags: java, selenium, tomcat, service

I deployed my restAPI as war in tomcat which is running as a service. I'm triggering a batch job in restAPI since i'm running my tomcat as a service, my batch which was supposed to run in foreground also runs in the background.

Please find the restAPI below:

```
@GET
    @Path("/triggerbatch")

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String TriggerTomcat(@QueryParam("url") String url,@QueryParam("srno") String srno) throws Exception {


        startApplicationBat(url,srno);

        System.out.println("Trigger  Batch");



        JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
        test.put("success", true);
        return test.toJSONString();
    }
```

Method to trigger Batch:

```
 public void startApplicationBat(String url, String srno) throws InterruptedException{
            Process p;
            {
                   try {
                       System.out.println("cmd /c start /wait C:\\CI_CD\\StartBat.bat " + url  + " "+ srno );
                       p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait C:\\CI_CD\\StartBat.bat   "  + url  + " "+ srno);
                     //  Thread.sleep(2000);
                 //p.waitFor();
                } catch (IOException  e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        }
```

The problem here is , in my batch job i'm executing a selenium java program which launches a browser and takes screenshot at 1 second interval using Robot. Since the batch runs in the background it is not opening any GUI so it captures only black screen.

Please find the selenium java code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Jar\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.out.println("Main thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        Capture();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://demo.testfire.net");
        StopCapture();
```

i'm running my robot in timer task to capture the screenshot in 1 sec interval. Please find the code to screenshot below:

```
Robot r = new Robot(); 

            // It saves screenshot to desired path 
            String path = "D:// Shot.jpg"; 

            // Used to get ScreenSize and capture image 
            Rectangle capture =  
            new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()); 
            BufferedImage Image = r.createScreenCapture(capture); 
            ImageIO.write(Image, "jpg", new File(path)); 
            System.out.println("Screenshot saved");
```

Any advise on how to run the batch in foreground should be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: In order to help you to fix a specific issue with your code we need to be able to replicate your environment. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57375472/edit) to include a [mcve] of the code you're using, fully explain what's happening contrary to what you coded, and show us what you have tried in fixing the issue yourself. Please also review each of the tags attached to your question, to ensure that each is valid, _in order that specialists in each of those categories see your question_.

Comment: May I suggest doing something with VBscript? You are able to bring applications to the foreground using it

Comment: Could you please help me with a working examples that would be really helpful